# Jquery Ajax requests work very very slow when on mobile

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, laravel, performance

I've created a live search form in `laravel`, using `jQuery ajax` on `keyup`.
I'm using a `datalist` to add the `options` to the `datalist`.
My database has around 3000 records of all German cities and when the user starts typing in the `datalist`, the `ajax request` is sent to the server and all possible cities are returned to my page.
This is my query:

```
$cities = DB::table('cities')->where($city,'like',$request->search.'%')->pluck($city);
```

This is my jQuery ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({

        type : 'get',

        url : '/'+'en'+'/search',

        data:{'search':search_value,country:country,'_token':token},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            $('#cities').empty();
                var citylist='';
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                citylist+="<option value='" + item + "'>"
            });
             $('#cities').append(citylist);
        }

    });
```

This code works super fast on a normal browser on a `computer` or `laptop` but as soon as I try it on a `mobile device` it hangs and doesn't response.
I get all `200 code` back which means that the `request` and `response` was successful but when I type the first letter I have to wait a minute long to see the newly added `options` and wait another minute for each newly entered letter.
My connection is `4G super fast`.
The same problem appears when I go to `responsive mode` in my `firefox` or `chrome` browser in my `pc`.
I'm very confused about the problem and any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Measure how long the `success` function takes to complete: Put `console.time('success');` at the begining and `console.timeEnd('success');` at the end.

Comment: I'm not at work now but the response comes as soon as I release the key and no difference between the desktop version.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `async: false` inside your ajax.